# How to disable xDB related search indexes in SItecore 9.1?

Tags: xdb, content-search

I am trying to reduce amount of indexes (I want to remove all xdb, fxm, marketing indexes), but sitecore documentation is not helpful with it.
I created patch to disable Xdb and Tracking and to delete marketing indexes from configuration, but Content Editor stopped working after deletion of indexes.
Also I added `<add key="exmEnabled:define" value="no" />` in Web.config

There was a detailed answer for Sitecore 8: [How to disable xDB related search indexes, when using CMS-only mode?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8314/how-to-disable-xdb-related-search-indexes-when-using-cms-only-mode)

Maybe someone has such manual for Sitecore 9, because structure of configs was changed a lot.

Comment: If you have disabled the xDB, you must also disable the Email Experience Manager (EXM). If you are only disabling tracking, you do not have to disable EXM.
in web.config do this <add key="exmEnabled:define" value="no" />

Comment: Also, did you disabled connection strings entry of xdb related database as well?

Comment: Nope, I didn't disable connection strings, will try this, thank you.

Comment: And I forgot to mention that I disabled exm as well ( Updated question )

Comment: @GauravAgarwal, I commented connection strings for xdb and marketing and still getting an error with missed marketing index in the content editor

Comment: I think the issue here is that marketing, specifically testing, is baked into the content editor. So deleting the marketing indexes causes all the issue. Disabling the xDB and turning off the index and service causes no errors for me. But the testing indexes seem to be required.

Comment: @ChrisAuer, I was able to remove all marketing indexes except sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web